# Count unique occurrences per each distinct variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique

My table is structured like this:

Table name `my_table`

```
name shop_id
____ _______
Mark aaa
Mark aaa
Mark bbb
Mark ccc
Mark ddd
Mark ddd
Jane aaa
Jane aaa
Jane bbb
Cody aaa
```

I want to find:

1. how many times a visitor went to stores in total
2. how many unique shops did the visitor go to.

For question 1, I figured the code should be this:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  count(name) as name_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name_count DESC
```

But I can't figure the second part. Help please! It should be something like this:

```
name shop_count
____ _______
Mark 4
Jane 2
Cody 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired outcome for BOTH parts of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` for unique shops

```
SELECT 
  name,
  COUNT(name) as name_count
  COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) AS unique_shop
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name_count DESC
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff complexity of `COUNT(*)` is more than `COUNT(name)`

Comment: @aRvi . . . That is not true in any database I'm familiar with.  And given that `count(*)` does *less* (just counting rows rather than checking to see if a value is not `NULL` in each row), I expect this to generalize to all databases.