# MySQL count number of times a result appears after grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a very similar problem to this one:
[Count unique occurrences per each distinct variable in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965464/count-unique-occurrences-per-each-distinct-variable-in-mysql) but with a twist.

I'm working with a select statement that shows results much like what the above-mentioned question does.

If I boil down my statement into a simple form for this question my code looks like this:

```
SELECT
    salesman,
    brand
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    sales.date=something
GROUP BY salesman, brand
```

Resulting in an example output like this:

```
salesman brand
____ _______
Mark aaa
Mark bbb
Mark ccc
Mark ddd
Jane aaa
Jane bbb
Cody aaa
```

Without the `GROUP BY` part the results might look like this:

```
salesman brand
____ _______
Mark ddd
Jane bbb    
Mark aaa
Cody aaa
Mark ddd
Jane aaa
Mark aaa
Jane aaa
Mark ccc
Mark bbb
```

The twist I have is that I want to count the number of times each brand appears after the grouping and output it in the same table of results.

EG:

```
salesman brand brand_count
____ _______ _____
Mark aaa 3
Mark bbb 2
Mark ccc 1
Mark ddd 1
Jane aaa 3
Jane bbb 2
Cody aaa 3
```

I've tried adding `count(*)` to the `SELECT` but that only returns the number 2 for salesman Mark with brand aaa and 1 for Cody, which isn't what I'm after.

I want to show for each brand the number of times it appeared in the results.
So brand aaa for example shows 3 times.

I suspect there might be a subquery needed though I'm not sure how it would work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:
Original MySQL code below in case it helps**

```
select
    ARM.SALESMAN AS 'SalesmanNumber',
    INM.BRAND AS 'Brand'
from
    ARMASTER ARM
    LEFT JOIN ARTRAN ART ON ARM.NUMBER = ART.CUST_NO
    LEFT JOIN INTRAN INTR ON ART.REF = INTR.REF
    LEFT JOIN ARSALECD SALESMAN ON ARM.SALESMAN = SALESMAN.CODE
    LEFT JOIN INMASTER INM ON INTR.STOCK_CODE = INM.CODE
where
    ARM.AREA = 01
    AND ARM.CUSTTYPE <> '99'
    AND ARM.SALESMAN NOT IN (24,48,49,50,51,52,71,72,74,90)
    AND (
        (YEAR(INTR.DATE) = YEAR(@mth) AND MONTH(INTR.DATE) = MONTH(@mth))
        OR (YEAR(DATE_ADD(@mth, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND MONTH(INTR.DATE) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(@mth, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)))
        OR (YEAR(DATE_ADD(@mth, INTERVAL -2 MONTH)) AND MONTH(INTR.DATE) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(@mth, INTERVAL -2 MONTH)))
        )
group by Brand , SalesmanNumber;
```

I tried making the select part of the statement look like this per Robo suggestion:

```
    ARM.SALESMAN AS 'SalesmanNumber',
    INM.BRAND AS 'Brand',
    (
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        INMASTER AS s
    WHERE
        s.BRAND=INMASTER.BRAND
    ) AS brand_count
```

But get this error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'INMASTER.BRAND' in 'where clause'

Also, I'm working with an old database version: MySQL 5.1.60

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That sounds like a rather different query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an older MySQL version you can use:

```
select s.salesman,s.brand,brand_count
from sales s
inner join (select brand,count(brand) as brand_count
            from ( select salesman,brand
                   from sales 
                   group by salesman,brand
                 ) as tbl
            group by brand     
           ) as x on x.brand=s.brand
group by salesman,brand,brand_count
order by s.salesman  ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/EevII2mZ

Group by the result , in an outer query count the brand and then use that as a subquery to join with the primary same table

Comment: Thanks, this one got me over the line. The fiddle link was really helpful too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT
    salesman,
    brand,
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            sales AS s
        WHERE
            s.brand=sales.brand
    ) AS brand_count
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    sales.date=something
GROUP BY salesman, brand
```

Comment: Thanks Robo, I tried doing as you suggested but it comes back with the error:
unknown column in where clause.
The column is definitely there though.

I'll add my original query code to the question in case all the joins and things are a factor.

Comment: @MarkWilliams strange, I checked in my database and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL v8+, you can use `COUNT() OVER ()` function.

Create table & data example:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
  salesman VARCHAR(255),
  brand VARCHAR(255),
  date DATE);

INSERT INTO sales VALUES
('Mark','ddd','2022-10-06'),
('Jane','bbb','2022-10-06'),
('Mark','aaa','2022-10-06'),
('Cody','aaa','2022-10-06'),
('Mark','ddd','2022-10-06'),
('Jane','aaa','2022-10-06'),
('Mark','aaa','2022-10-06'),
('Jane','aaa','2022-10-06'),
('Mark','ccc','2022-10-06'),
('Mark','bbb','2022-10-06');
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    salesman,
    brand,
    COUNT(brand) OVER (PARTITION BY Brand) AS brand_count
FROM
    sales
WHERE date='2022-10-06'
GROUP BY salesman, brand
ORDER BY salesman DESC, brand
```

Results:

| salesman | brand | brand_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | aaa | 3 |
| Mark | bbb | 2 |
| Mark | ccc | 1 |
| Mark | ddd | 1 |
| Jane | aaa | 3 |
| Jane | bbb | 2 |
| Cody | aaa | 3 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KnRGse7F)

For older MySQL version:

```
SELECT t1.salesman, t1.brand, brand_count
  FROM sales t1
  JOIN

/*this part of the query is just to get the brand_count*/
(SELECT brand, COUNT(*) AS brand_count
  FROM
(SELECT salesman, brand
FROM sales
WHERE date='2022-10-06'
GROUP BY salesman, brand) t
  GROUP BY brand) t2
/*this part of the query is just to get the brand_count*/

ON t1.brand=t2.brand
  WHERE t1.date='2022-10-06'
GROUP BY t1.salesman, t1.brand
  ORDER BY t1.salesman DESC, t1.brand;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wgSU4oHE)

Comment: This probably is the way to do it as well, however, I'm working with MySQL 5.1.60 and it cannot be updated. Meaning I believe the PARTITION BY function isn't available (available from v5.6).

Comment: I was half expecting that. I know it's possible to do it on older MySQL version but the query will be much longer.